# How to get a particular time in a java.util.Date in Java 8

Tags: java, date

For eg - I want 21:30 as the java.util.Date

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,21);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date d = cal.getTime();
```

Is there a better way to do it in Java 8 ?

I want it in java.util.Date only as I want to pass a Date in endAt() method in Quartz api while building a Trigger.

Comment: ... but why ... `Date` is the dark side. Come to the light and use [`java.time`](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro).

Comment: @akuzminykh - I want to pass a Date in endAt() method in Quartz api while building a Trigger.

Comment: 21:30 is not a date, it is time. `java.util.Date` does  not let you manage time but date+time. As @akuzminykh said, DON'T use `java.util.Date`, it is broken.

Comment: @RohitT There are many ways to have backwards compatibility to `Date` from `java.time`. There are even methods and functions just for that. You don't need to use any of the old API beside the backwards compatibility stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion of the new java.time classes to java.util.Date usually go through the `Instant` class. For example, to convert LocalTime 21:30 using today's date and the system time zone you can use:

```
LocalTime nineThirty = LocalTime.of(21, 30);

Date d = Date.from(Instant.from(nineThirty.atDate(LocalDate.now())
                                          .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())))
```

For Quartz specifically, you may want to use the [`DateBuilder` class from Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DateBuilder.html) instead of the legacy `Calendar` class.

```
Date d = DateBuilder.todayAt(21, 30, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Joni....Just what i needed...really appreciate it a lot.